# Android fbconnect how to forget login and password

Tags: android, fbconnect

I am using the following android fb connect library.

http://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/

problem is after successful login, if you logout and then click again on login button it open window asking for username and password but it already displays login and password of previous user. i think it is store login and password in the cookie how can i enforce to do not remember the login and password after logout ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it automatically fills in the text boxes, that means you told your browser to remember the credentials. Remember, fbconnect uses a WebView to let you login.

In other words, I don't think you can enforce the browser not to remember the credentials programmatically. It's up to the user to do this.

Answer (score 2):

Open FbDialog.java and find this code:

```
private void setUpWebView() {
    if(mWebView==null){
        mWebView = new WebView(getContext());
    }
    mWebView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new FbDialog.FbWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl(mUrl);
    mWebView.setLayoutParams(FILL);
    mContent.addView(mWebView);
}
```

Then add this code to force webview not to remember password:

```
    WebSettings mWebSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setSavePassword(false);
```

Comment: This is the right answer. It should have the green checkmark.